# SQL Query Too Complex To Express In JPA Criteria API?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, criteria

I have an SQL query that gets me exactly the data I need. The problem is that we are trying to express all queries in JPA Criteria API to maintain portability, and I can't figure out how to map this particular query.

The problem is that the JPA Criteria API Subquery class lacks the  multiselect() method that CriteriaQuery class has. As you can see in the SQL query, I have computed fields in the sub-query which don't exist in the entity. Thus, I have no way to retrieve these fields.

I would be quite appreciative if anyone knows a solution or could offer guidance, or even if someone could validate that what I am trying to achieve in JPA Criteria API is not possible.

The SQL:

```
SELECT w.NAME   AS 'wave_name', 
   Count(*) AS 'num_lines', 
   Sum(qty_ordered) AS 'num_units', 
   Count(DISTINCT unit_of_work_id) AS 'num_units_of_work', 
   Sum(completed_units) AS 'completed_units', 
   ( Sum(completed_units) + Sum(qty_scratched) ) / Sum(qty_ordered) AS 'perc_completed_units' 
FROM   (SELECT t.id, 
           t.wave_id, 
           t.quantity_requested  AS 'qty_ordered', 
           t.quantity_scratched    AS 'qty_scratched', 
           t.unit_of_work_id     AS 'unit_of_work_id', 
           Ifnull(m.quantity, 0) AS 'qty_picked', 
           CASE 
             WHEN Ifnull(m.quantity, 0) > quantity_requested THEN 
             quantity_requested 
             ELSE Ifnull(m.quantity, 0) 
           END                   AS 'completed_units' 
    FROM   task t 
           LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT move.task_id, 
                                   Sum(quantity) AS 'quantity' 
                            FROM   move
                            GROUP  BY task_id) m 
                        ON m.task_id = t.id) s 
   JOIN wave w 
     ON w.id = s.wave_id 
GROUP  BY w.name;
```

The entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "task")
public class Task {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne (cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn (name = "wave_id", nullable = false)
    private Wave wave;

    @ManyToOne (cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn (name = "unit_of_work_id", nullable = false)
    private UnitOfWork unitOfWork;

    @OneToMany (cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "task")
    private Set<Move> moves = new HashSet<Move>();

    @Column (name = "quantity_requested")
    private Long quantityRequested;

    @Column (name = "quantity_scratched")
    private Long quantityScratched;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "wave")
public class Wave {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "wave", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Task> tasks = new HashSet<Task>();
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "unit_of_work")
public class UnitOfWork {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column (name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "unitOfWork", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Task> tasks = new HashSet<Task>();
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "move")
public class Move {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne (cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn (name = "task_id", nullable = false)
    private Task task;

    @Column (name = "quantity")
    private Long quantity;
}
```

Comment: Why only criteria query why not use named parameters or native query approach? If the query is that big it doesn't make sense to use criteria approach.

Comment: The project I am working on has a Criteria-based module that facilitates generically applying filters to "canned" Criteria queries that back specific data grids in the system. Up until this point, the "canned" queries have been relatively simple and this approach has sufficed. But as more complicated requirements present themselves, I have been struggling to make it generic enough for all queries. I think queries like the one in my example are strong evidence against the approach in general.

Comment: I have provided example as an alternative to criteria, check that. I don't think criteria is a good approach in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I would say use named parameters or native query approach for this.

For example:

Named parameters:

```
 public interface Repo extends JpaRepository<AEntity, String> { 
    @Query("select a from AEntity a where a.BEntity.name = :name")

    public aMethod( @Param("name") String name)
    }
```

OR

Native query approach:

```
public interface Repo extends JpaRepository<AEntity, String> {    
    @Query(value = "select * from Tablename t where t.name = :name", nativeQuery=true)

    public aMethod(@Param("name") String name)
    }
```

Check this link if you are using spring jpa

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/1.4.x/reference/htmlsingle/#jpa.named-parameters